# How to verify element displayed on a Relative Layout using Appium

Tags: appium-android

My requirement is to verify the presence of an element on a screen that appears when I perform certain action on Android App screen and then disappears within seconds. If I inspect this element, its shows as relative layout.
Is there a way I can verify the present of element on this kind of disappearing screen.

I tried to write the code to inspect and verify this element but my script fails 6/10 times with No Such Element Found exception. as the elements disappears from the page layout after sometime.